# How to run a group of Cucumber Feature files, one after another, in the same browser window?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

What I would like to do is to run multiple test cases in the same Web browser, one after the another, without closing the Web browser window, so we don’t have to repeat during the execution of each test case the same lines, like the ones related to the login.

I am working on the automation of test cases with the Cucumber JVM 1.2.2 framework and Selenium. Each test case corresponds to a Feature file.

So, at the end of the first test case, the second test case would continue to run in the same browser window where the first test case was executed, and a new browser window should not be started.

I tried to find an argument to configure the existing instance of the Chrome driver. I also defined in a Feature file, a Background and multiple Scenarios, but each Scenario started in a new browser window

To initialize the driver of Chrome

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", sharedData.chomeDriverPath );
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
sharedData.appInstance = new ChromeDriver( options );
sharedData.appInstance.get( util.sharedData.URLUnderTest );
sharedData.appInstance.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: U should look at this example of shared driver which does exactly what you are looking for - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v3.0.0/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same session, then instead of defining those test cases as scenarios you could turn them into test steps. However, it seems like that drifts off from the cucumber philosophy.

Comment: The problem of doing this (among many others) is that if one test fails, the rest of the tests won't be executed.